# Saving key-value data in app setting

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, application-settings

I want to use application settings for storing settings data for my application. I need save a list of some pair values string-string or int-string. I was finding out what types I can use there but there are only for selection some System.Collections.Specialized datatypes which are very obsolet and it makes code very messy. Which approach for storing a list of string-string or int-string pair values is the best?

Comment: Have you seen [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by "very obsolete"? Obsolete in what way? `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` stores string-string key-value pairs.